# How to convert Object into Array in vb.net

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a javascript that returns an array

```
var docArray = new Array(page, stamprect[0], stamprect[3], stamprect[2], stamprect[1],     srot);
return docArray;
```

and I'm trying to get VB.Net to read it into array

```
Dim stampInfo() As Integer
stampInfo = javaScriptObj.getAllGhostStamps(CInt(pages.Item(i)) - 1)
```

im getting error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type 'System.Int32[]'.
```

I dont know how to typecast it to array. any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast each item in the array to an integer.  For instance:

```
Dim raw() As Object = javaScriptObj.getAllGhostStamps(CInt(pages.Item(i)) - 1)
Dim stampInfo(raw.Length) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 to raw.Length - 1
    stampInfo(i) = CType(raw(i), Integer)
Next
```

Comment: Use DirectCast instead of CType http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx

Comment: @Yatrix The problem with DirectCast, as I understand it, is that it skips over using any custom defined operator overloads.  Since operator overloads can be very useful and I sometimes use them, I prefer to use CType.  I believe CType is the equivalent of a typical casting operation in C# (e.g. `int x = (int)y;`).